# Error on an Android Studio project while updating property:

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

When I was using React Native, I was using iOS, but when I moved to Andriod, I got an error that never showed up in iOS. It was:

Error while updating property 'secureTextEntry' of a view managed by: AndroidTextInput

java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean.

There were no errors in the build, so this is a problem with the code. (I am including a screenshot of Android Studio and the emulator just in case)

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

(Almost all of my code has TextInputs in them, but in the error, it is called AndroidTextInput even though in my code I use TextInput)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass secureTextEntry as a boolean and not a string:

`<TextInput  secureTextInput={true} />`